# Automate and simplify the check-in after code review completion in TFS

Tags: tfs, checkin-policy, tfs-code-review

I would like to **automate the code review process** to check in easily in Team Foundation Server.

It is possible to [add code review in the check-in policy](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/custom-code-review-checkin-policy), but the problem is that it creates a lot of **back and forth**, even if the code review is okay and there is no comment or modification to make.

Maybe it is possible to make it happen in a smoother way?

---

## Sketches (simplified on purpose)

What we can do with the actual code review workflow:

[image: Back and forth code review]

What I would like to do:

[image]

(hoping my sketches are understandable)

---

I'm thinking about developing a new extension if it doesn't exist.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a pull request. Pull requests are not available for TFVC at the moment, but are available for Git. My understanding is that pull requests will eventually be an option for TFVC.

Comment: Interesting idea! So maybe I could bypass the actual limits of TFVC?